# initialDelayString = "#{T(java.lang.Math.random()) * 300000}"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks

I’m changing the delay of launching the process with

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000, initialDelayString = "#{T(java.lang.Math.random()) * 300000}").
```

But When I run the server it generates this error "- cannot parse into integer" although I need the solution for the “initialDelayString” to do the random

Answer (score 0):

i change SPEL to `#{new Double((T(Math).random() * 30000)).intValue()}` and it works for me
note i changed the delay 300,000 to 30,000 :-D
results in my eclipse(debuuger mode to see the running conditions) are detailly below:

1. step into the initDelayString calculate in org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(Scheduled scheduled, Method method, Object bean), this run get 23601 millsecs [image: pic1]
2. jump the breakpoint and let the app goes, sees the console output ,the red area is the tick app started [11:49:37], and the green area is the task start after initialDelayString's value (see step 1) 23601 millsecs[11:50:00], and the yellow area is the output with fixrate by 5000 millsecs [11:50:05, 11:51:10 ...]
   [[image: pic2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kAUD.png)
3. by the way, the code of app i ran could be find in the [spring Scheduling Tasks guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/), it just a simple demo, hope it will help you!

Comment: thank you for you feedback,I did the same modification in SPEL But It generates this error :  Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'doProcessBusinessDate': Invalid initialDelayString value "#{new Double((T(Math).random() * 30000)).intValue()}" - cannot parse into integer

Comment: it sounds strange. i ran the code again and got no errors. I suggest you use this `#{new Double(3000.01).intValue()}` to do a test. Will this make your task start after 3000 millsecs delay? Or it still get error?

Comment: I did the modification for SPEL, I launched the server in debug but on the class’ ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor’ it recuperates the value of ‘ initialDelayString’ but once on the ‘initialDelayString = this.embeddedValueResolver.resolveStringValue(initialDelayString);’ the initialDelayString’ doesn’t change,  so the conversion for de #{new Double(3000.01).intValue()} to a value seems not working.
Once on the try catch it cannot parse the char to an integer so it launch the exception “cannot parse into integer”

Comment: So sad to heard that... Could you checkout the demo in https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ just try to have a test with the same SpEL that I had used. In that way we may find that reason more exactly

Comment: Is it possible to tell me wich version of Spring you use ?
can you tell me what do you have on the list embeddedValueResolvers , When you launch your application with a breakpoint for  resolveEmbeddedValue please?

Comment: My application (same as the demo in spring's guide excepted the initialDelayString value) use spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.3.RELEASE, and actually the spring-core 4.3.8.RELEASE. And the embeddedValueResolver's full package is `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver@ADDRESS` when it running. I strongly suggest you run the demo for test. It is a easy way to make sure that we have the same codes and same environment. Have you checked out the codes and ran it successfully?

Comment: Could you just test the annotation with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000, initialDelayString="#{3000}")` ? Will it run successfully ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZjEd.png

Yes , I did te test but the same problem, on the class ‘AbstractBeanFactory’ Can you please do a breakpoint on the sur result = resolver.resolveStringValue(result); and then tell me what do you have in the list ‘embeddedValueResolvers’ ?
Thank u

Comment: the 'embeddedValueResolvers' 
just have one element `[org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2@ADDRESS]`

Comment: On this line fixedDelayString = this.embeddedValueResolver.resolveStringValue(fixedDelayString); on resolveStringValue do toi have the same thing with me :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SYN8.png

Comment: What do you mean by ` on resolveStringValue do toi have the same thing with me `? Can you please show me the application's struct you are running ? About the pom.xml(or gradle?) and the classes codes ?

Comment: These are my application structure: [CODES](https://timgsa.baidu.com/timg?image&quality=80&size=b10000_10000&sec=1499912487&di=91c50285e355cf752be342da1f6fe6cc&imgtype=jpg&src=http%3A%2F%2Fe.hiphotos.baidu.com%2Fimage%2Fpic%2Fitem%2Fe7cd7b899e510fb31be78a3fd333c895d0430c9f.jpg) and [pom.xml](https://timgsa.baidu.com/timg?image&quality=80&size=b10000_10000&sec=1499912711&di=e704dfb4208f5f12c464b88533d6a4c4&imgtype=jpg&src=http%3A%2F%2Fc.hiphotos.baidu.com%2Fimage%2Fpic%2Fitem%2Fc995d143ad4bd113692e4b9a50afa40f4afb05b2.jpg).